# Don't I need 2K+ rep on a site before I can edit without review?

Tags: support, edits

I was surprised that I was able to provide [this edit](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/revisions/106202/4) to [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/106202/my-boss-wants-a-narrated-line-by-line-english-explanation-of-our-code) without review. Is this a bug, or has there been a policy change about rep needed to freely edit posts?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No it's not a bug. As it was comunity wiki post, and you need only 100 rep do edit it.
[FAQ: Edit community wiki questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit-community-wiki)

Comment: Ah, I knew that. >:| I'm not very observant today.